# HighCharts is it possible to pass an object to pointer config of Gauge chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to configure a highchart gauge chart and to pass an object with a name and value to the pointer but it seems the only input it gets is an array with one number. Is there any way to add a text along with the value of the pointer?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erzbk2sy/) here
This is the part I'm struggling:

```
{
            type: 'gauge',
            data: [30], // how to add an object here? {name:"some name", data:30}
            name: "tesccccct",
            title: { //this does not work either
                text: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 80
            },
            dial: {
                rearLength: 0
            }
        }],
```

Comment: Can't you use the `name: "tesccccct",` for your `some name` string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of objects but in the right structure:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    data: [{
        name: "some name",
        y: 30
    }]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/as0d8fgL/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge.data